# How can I get the total size of .conf extension in directory /etc and save them into another file?

Tags: bash, scripts

How can I get the total size with bytes of .conf extension in directory /etc and save them into total_size.txt using Bash Script.

Here's my script:-

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /home/onyic/total_size.txt
echo "$(du -csh -B1 /etc/*.conf)" >> ~/total_size.txt
```

I know that echo actually just print it. That's why I need your help.

The updated version of my script:-

```
#!bin/bash
find /etc -name '*.conf' -print0 | du -csh -B1 --files0-from=- | awk 'END {print $1}' >> ~/total_size.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this method, you'll miss files like `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, which are in subdirectories of `/etc`. You should use `find` to select files for `du`:

```
find /etc -name '*.conf' -print0 | du --files0-from=-
```

Then you can use `awk` to get the total from last line:

```
find /etc -name '*.conf' -print0 | du --files0-from=- | awk 'END {print $1}'
```

You already know how to put the output in a file.

- `find /etc -name '*.conf' -print0` lists files (well, anything really) in `/etc` whose names match `*.conf`, but with a null byte after each filename (`-print0`). Since null bytes are not allowed in filenames, it's perfect for separating filenames.
- `du --files0-from=-` reads filenames from standard input (`-`) separated by null bytes (that's why e used `-print0` with `find`)
- `awk 'END {print $1}'` just prints the first column (`$1`) of the last line.

Comment: I think this may works, but I am having a problem that when I  run the script and do "cat" the file is empty.

Comment: Can you post the updated version of your script in the question?

Comment: That command works correctly for me. `cat ~/total_size.txt` shows `1359872` (actual number may vary).

Comment: What permissions did you give your file "total_size.txt" ?

Comment: Nothing special. Whatever was the default.

Comment: Worked. One last question, can you update your answer with explaining what every command do?

Comment: @Onyic updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the total size, that's the last line of `du`'s output:

```
$ du -csh -B1 /etc/*.conf
4096    /etc/asound.conf
...
192512  total
```

You can use `tail`+`cut` to get that value:

```
$ du -csh -B1 /etc/*.conf  | tail -n1 | cut -f1
192512
```

`tail` to take the last line, `cut` to take the first column.
So:

```
du -csh -B1 /etc/*.conf  | tail -n1 | cut -f1 >> ~/total_size.txt
```

By the way, the `touch ...` is useless. The shell will create the file if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
stat -c %s /etc/*.conf | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print total}' > ~/total_size.txt
```

or if you like "du" du without -b switch gives disk usage, -b switch gives file size in bytes.

> du --help
>
> Usage: du [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> -b, --bytes           equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1'

```
du -bc /etc/*.conf | cut -f1 | tail -1 > ~/total_size.txt
```

The difference:

```
$ du -csh -B1 /etc/*.conf  | tail -n1 | cut -f1
208896
$ du -bc /etc/*.conf | cut -f1 | tail -1
108396
$ stat -c %s /etc/*.conf | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print total}' 
108396
```

Comment: [@terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) edited. Removed `ls` as you said. Thanks for pointing out the flaws.